# How do I set custom tracer in ModelCamelContext?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am implementing simple camel application using camel 3.14.0.

I start using modelcamelcontext.
But there is below exception during setting custom tracer.

```
2022-04-29 17:04:18.474  INFO 10264 --- [           main] target.atom.engine.EngineApplication     : Started EngineApplication in 14.158 seconds (JVM running for 16.177)
2022-04-29 17:04:18.540 ERROR 10264 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set tracer on a started CamelContext
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.setTracer(AbstractCamelContext.java:4601) ~[camel-base-engine-3.14.0.jar:3.14.0]
    at target.atom.common.config.TargetAtomConfig.reloadRoutes(TargetAtomConfig.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
    at target.atom.common.config.TargetAtomConfig$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7b88810d.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
```

How do I set tracer in modelCamelContext?

source code

```
ModelCamelContext modelCamelContext = camelContext.adapt(ModelCamelContext.class);
TraceFormatter formatter = new TraceFormatter();
modelCamelContext.setTracer(formatter.getTracer(modelCamelContext));
modelCamelContext.setTracing(true);
…
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Camel Spring Boot, the `CamelContext` can be customized thanks to a bean of type [`CamelContextConfiguration`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel.springboot/camel-spring-boot/latest/org/apache/camel/spring/boot/CamelContextConfiguration.html) that is meant to be used to add custom logic before and after Spring Boot and the `CamelContext` have been fully started.

In your case, the idea is to add custom logic before the start up, so your code should look like this:

```
@Bean
CamelContextConfiguration contextConfiguration() {
    return new CamelContextConfiguration() {
        @Override
        public void beforeApplicationStart(CamelContext context) {
            // Configure the tracer before starting up the camel context
            TraceFormatter formatter = new TraceFormatter();
            context.setTracer(formatter.getTracer(modelCamelContext));
            context.setTracing(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterApplicationStart(CamelContext camelContext) {
            // Nothing to do
        }
    };
}
```